# How to print data from the inbuilt printer of an android Pos terminal using serial port

Tags: android, mobile, serial-port, port, pos

I have an android mobile pos device with an inbuilt printer, I want to communicate with the inbuilt printer by finding the serial port which the printer is connected to and send data to the printer using the port.. How do I go about this..

Comment: Based on the device vendor and model information, ask the vendor's support desk for a manual or SDK.

Comment: I have the vendor sdk but i don't want to use it, I want to communicate the printer directly myself

Comment: In that case, for example, find out what you think is good from these search results and use it, or try to create a program yourself with reference. [escpos](https://github.com/topics/escpos), [thermal-printing](https://github.com/topics/thermal-printing)